# How to install and use an Event Filter written in Qt C++ in a QML application

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt-quick

I have a situation where I need to add keyboard shortcuts to an application that is mainly comprised of a QtQuick user interface.  The version of Qt Quick is unfortunately locked to Qt5.3 and Shortcuts (the way we need them) were only introduced in Qt5.5 and Qt5.7 respectively.

So, as a solution, I wrote an event filter that functions similarly to QShortcut (can't use QShortcut, hence the event filter).

Does anybody know how to install and use this eventfilter in QML?

Answer (score 12):

One way would be to expose a singleton type to QML:

```
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtQml>

class ShortcutListener : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    ShortcutListener(QObject *parent = nullptr) :
        QObject(parent)
    {
    }

    Q_INVOKABLE void listenTo(QObject *object)
    {
        if (!object)
            return;

        object->installEventFilter(this);
    }

    bool eventFilter(QObject *object, QEvent *event) override
    {
        if (event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress) {
            QKeyEvent *keyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent*>(event);
            qDebug() << "key" << keyEvent->key() << "pressed on" << object;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};

static QObject *shortcutListenerInstance(QQmlEngine *, QJSEngine *engine)
{
    return new ShortcutListener(engine);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    qmlRegisterSingletonType<ShortcutListener>("App", 1, 0, "ShortcutListener", shortcutListenerInstance);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

`main.qml`:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

import App 1.0

Window {
    id: window
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    Component.onCompleted: ShortcutListener.listenTo(window)
}
```

If you have several different listeners, you could also do it declaratively by adding an `object` property to `ShortcutListener` that it would install an event filter on when set.

For more info, see [Integrating QML and C++](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-topic.html).

Comment: Thanks Mitch, this is a rather complete answer!  I don't have a QtQuick window to work with, the main window renders from a QQuickItem.  The QQuickItem does have access to the window through a pointer, perhaps I can try that.

Comment: I could be wrong, but it shouldn't matter what the root item is, so long as it gets key events.

Comment: You might be right.  Drawback though, if the object that the event filter is installed on is not visible/doesn't have focus, a call to grabKeyboard() is required to force the input triggers to pass through that object.  This is not something I wish to do, as there are other QAction items that have shortcuts configured outside my event filter.

Comment: Right, but the root item should always get ignored events?

Comment: Good question.  At the moment, nothing is getting through.  Something lower down is absorbing my events. :-(

Comment: How to connect to property into qml like `shiftHold`, because I defined by `Q_Property` but not working in qml ));